# Image to data uri without base64

Tags: javascript, html

I have image as base64 data URI but want to convert it to Data URI without base64 (in my case image size doesn't matter) - how to do it? This is what I try so far

```js
let imgB64="Qk3KAAAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAAHQAAACMAAAABAAEAAAAAAIwAAADDDgAAww4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP///wD//f/4//B/+P/tv/j/nc/4/n3z+P39/fjx+Px45uUzuJddz8h3vd/wd73f8He93/BvvN/wX78f8D+f3/BOZz/wdfr/8Hv9//B7+f/we+X/8Hvd//B73f/we93/8GTd/nBfUniQP4+m6L/f3tjP396489/eeP3f2fj+X9f4/5/P+P/Pv/j/8n/4//3/+A";

let imgStr=atob(imgB64);                                 // decode base 64 to str
let bytes=Uint8Array.from(imgStr, c => c.charCodeAt(0)); // string to bytes

picB64.src='data:image;base64,'+imgB64                      // this works 

pic.src='data:image;text/plain,'+encodeURIComponent(bytes); // this not work :(
```

```html
<div>This works</div> <img id="picB64">

<div>This not works</div> <img id="pic">
```

Here is example showing that this is possible (probably partially broken but works)

```html
<img src=data:image;text/plain,BMv%0A%00%00%00%00%00%00x%00%00%00(%00%00%00%40%00%00%00%40%00%00%00%01%00%04%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%C3%84%0E%00%00%C3%84%0E%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%2B%C2%81%C3%BC%00%08%1F%C3%8D%00%08Zr%00%C3%BC%C3%BA%C3%BC%00%5E%5E%5E%00%119%C2%B9%00%08%C2%93%0B%00%C2%AB%C2%AB%C2%AB%00%00%C3%BF%00%00%00%C3%BF%00%00%00%C3%BF%C3%BC%00%C3%BC%C3%BF%C2%AB%00%C2%AB%C3%BF%00%00%00%C3%BF%00%00%00%C3%BF%00%00%00%00%00%02%00%03%01%03%00%01%01%02%03%03%03%02%03%03%02%00%03%01%01%01%03%03%03%02%03%01%02%02%01%02%01%00%00%00%01%03%00%00%02%00%02%01%02%00%02%01%03%03%01%01%02%01%01%02%00%01%02%02%03%00%01%02%03%00%01%01%01%01%03%01%02%01%01%02%03%02%02%03%00%00%00%02%01%01%02%01%02%01%00%03%00%02%02%03%01%03%01%02%02%02%02%00%01%01%02%00%00%03%00%02%01%01%03%03%03%03%01%03%02%01%00%00%01%02%02%01%00%00%01%03%03%00%00%00%03%00%01%01%01%01%01%02%00%02%00%03%03%03%00%02%02%03%01%02%01%02%00%01%01%03%02%01%02%00%00%00%00%00%01%00%01%02%02%01%01%03%03%02%02%02%01%02%03%02%00%00%03%00%03%00%01%03%01%01%02%02%03%02%03%03%03%02%03%03%02%01%03%02%03%01%00%02%03%03%00%02%02%01%02%02%01%02%02%03%03%01%00%01%03%03%03%01%01%01%01%01%00%03%02%00%00%00%02%01%01%02%00%02%02%01%02%03%03%00%03%02%00%02%02%01%00%03%00%00%03%01%03%03%01%02%00%02%03%01%01%01%03%00%00%03%02%03%00%01%02%03%03%02%03%02%02%01%01%01%00%03%03%03%03%01%02%03%02%03%00%00%01%01%01%00%02%00%02%01%03%01%00%02%02%03%02%01%02%01%01%01%01%03%00%01%03%03%00%03%02%01%02%00%01%01%01%00%00%03%01%00%03%01%01%01%01%02%01%02%00%03%03%00%00%01%00%00%03%02%03%02%00%03%02%03%03%01%03%00%01%01%00%01%01%02%00%00%02%02%01%00%00%00%03%02%00%02%02%00%02%03%03%01%02%01%01%00%01%00%03%03%00%01%01%00%03%01%03%01%02%01%00%02%01%01%01%00%02%02%03%02%01%00%00%00%03%02%00%03%00%00%00%02%03%00%00%01%03%02%01%02%02%03%01%00%00%01%01%02%03%03%03%00%01%00%01%00%03%02%02%02%00%00%03%02%02%03%00%00%02%02%01%03%01%02%01%02%03%03%03%01%00%01%02%02%01%02%03%00%03%01%03%01%02%00%01%00%03%03%03%02%01%01%02%03%03%01%01%02%03%01%01%03%02%01%01%01%00%01%00%00%03%01%00%02%02%03%02%00%02%01%03%00%00%02%02%03%03%01%02%00%00%00%03%01%03%02%02%01%02%02%03%03%03%01%01%00%00%03%03%01%00%01%03%03%02%03%03%02%00%02%00%02%00%02%00%02%00%00%01%01%00%02%03%03%03%01%00%01%03%01%01%00%03%02%02%00%02%02%02%01%00%00%02%01%03%02%01%01%00%03%02%01%01%01%02%02%02%02%02%00%01%01%02%00%00%03%02%02%00%02%03%00%01%00%01%03%01%02%03%02%00%03%01%01%00%03%00%03%02%02%03%00%03%01%03%02%01%02%00%01%01%02%00%00%00%02%03%03%01%03%03%02%01%01%01%00%02%01%01%01%01%03%01%02%01%02%03%01%02%02%02%00%02%01%00%00%01%00%02%00%00%02%00%00%01%03%01%02%02%01%03%01%03%02%02%03%00%02%03%03%01%00%03%00%00%01%03%03%03%02%01%02%00%01%03%02%02%02%01%00%02%03%01%01%02%02%01%02%03%03%01%00%01%02%03%00%00%02%02%02%03%01%03%02%03%03%00%00%02%01%02%00%00%01%03%02%00%01%01%01%01%00%01%01%00%00%02%02%02%03%00%02%00%00%01%01%01%01%03%03%01%03%01%03%03%02%03%01%00%03%02%01%01%00%03%03%03%01%00%02%01%02%03%01%02%03%03%01%00%01%03%02%00%00%03%01%03%03%02%03%01%02%02%00%00%03%02%03%00%03%03%02%00%01%03%03%03%00%01%00%00%00%03%02%00%02%01%01%03%01%01%01%01%01%02%02%00%00%00%01%02%00%03%01%03%03%03%03%01%00%01%03%02%00%02%00%00%02%00%02%00%02%01%03%03%01%02%01%02%01%03%00%03%01%00%03%01%03%03%02%03%01%01%01%00%03%03%03%01%03%03%01%01%01%03%01%03%02%00%02%00%01%02%00%03%02%01%00%00%01%02%01%00%02%02%01%00%01%03%01%03%01%03%00%02%02%02%01%00%03%02%01%02%03%02%00%00%02%03%01%01%01%01%00%03%03%02%03%03%02%01%00%01%03%01%01%00%00%03%00%03%03%01%00%02%02%01%00%02%02%02%00%02%00%01%03%02%01%02%01%01%03%01%01%02%01%00%00%00%02%02%03%01%02%01%02%03%01%02%03%01%00%02%02%01%02%03%00%03%01%01%00%01%00%00%03%03%03%00%02%03%01%01%00%03%02%01%02%02%00%00%01%02%02%02%03%02%00%02%00%01%00%03%02%02%03%01%01%01%03%03%03%03%02%02%02%01%01%02%01%02%00%00%00%02%00%01%02%00%00%02%02%02%02%01%02%02%02%02%01%03%03%01%01%01%00%03%03%00%00%00%01%01%02%00%00%00%03%01%00%01%03%03%01%03%02%02%02%01%00%00%03%00%03%00%01%01%02%03%02%03%02%01%01%01%01%00%02%03%03%03%03%03%01%00%01%03%03%01%02%01%01%01%02%02%00%03%00%01%00%00%02%01%02%02%00%00%00%00%02%00%03%01%01%01%00%01%03%02%01%00%03%02%02%00%01%02%03%03%02%03%01%02%00%02%01%01%03%01%00%01%03%01%02%00%02%00%03%03%00%02%03%00%02%02%01%01%00%02%03%01%03%03%03%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%03%03%02%00%01%03%03%00%03%02%03%02%03%02%03%03%03%00%00%01%03%00%01%00%02%00%03%00%00%00%01%03%01%02%00%03%03%00%02%03%00%03%01%02%02%02%03%03%01%01%01%01%01%01%00%00%03%03%01%01%00%01%03%00%02%02%00%00%01%01%01%00%00%02%03%00%01%02%03%00%03%02%02%03%01%02%03%02%01%01%02%01%00%00%01%01%01%00%02%02%00%02%00%00%02%01%00%02%03%00%00%01%01%02%02%02%00%02%03%03%00%02%02%00%03%01%03%03%01%00%01%03%03%03%03%01%01%03%02%03%00%00%01%02%03%01%02%02%02%03%03%03%02%03%02%01%01%02%03%03%03%02%00%03%00%02%00%02%01%02%03%02%00%00%01%02%03%03%02%03%00%01%00%02%03%03%03%02%03%01%00%00%01%00%00%01%03%02%03%00%02%02%00%02%03%00%02%03%01%00%01%03%03%02%02%02%01%03%02%03%00%00%01%03%01%00%03%01%01%03%02%00%01%03%03%01%02%01%03%00%01%01%01%02%02%01%02%00%01%03%03%02%02%02%01%02%02%02%00%03%01%00%03%01%00%03%00%01%03%03%02%02%02%03%02%02%00%03%03%01%03%00%01%02%03%00%03%02%00%02%03%02%02%00%01%01%03%01%00%02%02%03%02%02%00%00%03%01%03%01%03%00%02%00%03%01%03%01%01%00%00%02%01%03%02%03%03%03%03%01%00%01%02%03%00%01%00%00%01%03%02%02%01%01%01%03%02%00%03%03%00%01%02%03%01%00%02%02%01%00%03%01%02%02%02%01%01%01%01%02%01%01%01%03%01%00%03%02%00%03%01%02%01%03%00%00%03%03%01%00%03%00%01%03%00%01%03%01%00%00%01%00%01%01%03%00%00%03%02%00%02%00%00%02%01%01%02%00%02%02%03%03%02%00%02%01%02%02%03%03%01%02%00%00%00%00%01%00%01%03%00%01%03%00%03%02%02%00%00%01%03%02%00%00%02%00%00%02%03%00%02%03%02%01%01%02%01%02%00%02%03%02%01%03%02%01%02%01%01%02%02%01%00%03%03%00%03%01%01%03%02%03%01%03%02%02%02%03%02%00%01%00%02%02%03%03%01%03%00%00%00%02%03%03%00%00%00%00%01%00%03%03%00%00%00%00%02%00%00%01%00%00%01%02%01%00%00%03%00%02%01%03%01%01%00%01%02%01%01%03%00%01%00%00%01%00%00%03%03%00%03%00%01%02%01%01%00%02%02%01%02%01%01%00%00%01%02%00%00%03%03%01%01%02%02%01%03%03%00%00%02%02%01%00%00%01%01%03%01%01%03%02%00%03%03%00%00%00%03%02%01%00%00%02%03%03%00%02%03%03%01%01%03%00%03%01%02%03%01%01%02%00%03%01%00%03%01%00%01%03%01%03%01%03%01%03%01%00%00%02%02%00%02%00%03%02%00%01%02%01%03%02%02%02%01%01%00%03%00%03%03%01%00%03%00%02%01%00%03%03%00%01%03%03%01%00%01%01%03%03%02%03%00%00%01%01%00%00%01%02%03%00%00%01%03%00%02%00%01%01%01%03%01%00%03%01%03%01%03%02%03%00%01%00%02%03%03%01%02%00%00%02%02%02%02%03%01%03%01%00%01%00%02%00%00%03%03%00%00%00%02%01%02%00%02%00%02%03%02%03%00%03%02%01%03%03%01%00%00%01%01%03%00%03%00%00%02%00 >
```

Comment: why don't you try to convert it to blob

Comment: Can you specify what your goal is that makes you not want to use Base64 data?

Comment: I need to omit base64 encoding algorithm to reduce size of progam (not in JS) which generate images

Comment: To reduce image output or the size of the program?

Comment: size of the program

Comment: So you've asked us a JavaScript question which appears to be about data-uri encoding an image (in JavaScript) but you then say (in your comment) _"reduce size of progam (not in JS)"_ Which one is it? Perhaps you could show us the code that is generating the base64 encoded image and state what the problem is that means you cannot use base64 encoding.

Comment: the base64 encoding is made to convert binary data into plain text so that it can be safely included in html page. so I am not sure you will be able to reduce the size with another binary to text conversion algo.

Comment: @Tuckbros question is not about image size - as I emphasise: *in my case image size doesn't matter*

Comment: Yes, your concern is about the size of the encoding "tool". The first question you have to answer (and I don't know the answer yet to help you) is : What encoding is supported as image format for an URI ? and then : What is the weight of the algo needed to encode it in your tool ?

Comment: @Tuckbros - Lanki gives answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024742/860099) (7 hours ago...) which solved all my problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible to render image without base64 encoding.

Here is it:

```js
//function for convert byte array to hex
function toHexString(byteArray) {
  return Array.from(byteArray, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('%')
}

//image in base64
var imgB64="Qk3KAAAAAAAAAD4AAAAoAAAAHQAAACMAAAABAAEAAAAAAIwAAADDDgAAww4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP///wD//f/4//B/+P/tv/j/nc/4/n3z+P39/fjx+Px45uUzuJddz8h3vd/wd73f8He93/BvvN/wX78f8D+f3/BOZz/wdfr/8Hv9//B7+f/we+X/8Hvd//B73f/we93/8GTd/nBfUniQP4+m6L/f3tjP396489/eeP3f2fj+X9f4/5/P+P/Pv/j/8n/4//3/+A";

//base64 to string
var imgStr=atob(imgB64);

//make byte array
var bytes=Uint8Array.from(imgStr, c => c.charCodeAt(0));

//transform input array into hex array
var hexBytes = "data:image,%" + toHexString(bytes);

//set image to element
document.getElementById("pic").src = hexBytes;
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="pic">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I looking for :)

Comment: long-oneliner: `pic.src = "data:image," + [...atob(imgB64)].map(x=>'%'+x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')).join\`\`;`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the content of a data-uri is either textual or base64 encoded binary data.

From MDN [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

> Data URLs are composed of four parts: a prefix (data:), a MIME type indicating the type of data, an optional base64 token if non-textual, and the data itself:
>
> `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`
>
> The mediatype is a MIME type string, such as 'image/jpeg' for a JPEG image file. If omitted, defaults to text/plain;charset=US-ASCII
>
> If the data is textual, you can simply embed the text (using the appropriate entities or escapes based on the enclosing document's type). ***Otherwise, you can specify base64 to embed base64-encoded binary data.*** You can find more info on MIME types here and here.

To use binary data with a data-uri *requires* binary data be base64 encoded. Sorry

**UPDATE**

It seems that you have come across a "work-around", although this allows you to use url encoded text within the data-uri, it is goung to be even larger than the base64 encoding.

Base 64 encodes 3 bytes on binary data in to 4 bytes of ASCII. Resulting in a (approximately) 33% increase in size. URL Encoding a single byte will result in 3 characters resulting in a 200% increase in size.

This increase in size is exactly what you are trying to avoid though.

Comment: No - this is POSSIBLE - I update the question (example in the bottom)

Comment: That is kind of a work around and converts non-ascii/utf-8 data in to 3 characters. This is likely to be worse than base64

Comment: But instead of a 33% increase in size with base64 you have a nearly 200% increase in size, exactly what you didn't want.

Comment: no - the output image size doesnt matter for me - read comments below question for more info